# Perl script to check disk usage

Tags: perl, linux, email

I'm looking for input on the code itself and formatting/style.  This script parses the output of `df -h` on a Linux server and emails the user if the usage percentage is above the threshold (90% in this case).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Mail::Sendmail;

my $svr = `hostname`;
my @output = `df -h`;
my $msg;
my $mailto = 'someone@foo.com';
my $threshold = 90;

sub main
{
  foreach (@output) {
    if (($_ =~ m/(\d+)% (.*)/) && ( $1 > $threshold )) {
      chomp($svr); $msg = "$svr: $2 volume  is $1 percent full\n" }
    }

    my %mail = ( To      => $mailto,
                 From    => 'Server@foo.com',
                 Subject => "$svr has a full file system",
                 Message => $msg
               );

  if ( defined $msg ) {
    sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;
  }

}

main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug here:

> ```
> foreach (@output) {
>     if (($_ =~ m/(\d+)% (.*)/) && ( $1 > $threshold )) {
>       chomp($svr); $msg = "$svr: $2 volume  is $1 percent full\n" }
>     }
> ```

If there are more than one partitions full, `$msg` will contain only the last one. I think you want to append to `$msg` instead of overwriting. I suggest to rewrite like this:

```
chomp(my $svr = `hostname`);

foreach (@output) {
    if (m/(\d+)% (.*)/ && $1 > $threshold) {
        $msg .= "$svr: $2 volume is $1 percent full\n";
    }
}
```

Explanation of other improvements:

- Removed unnecessary brackets from the `if` condition
- Simplified `$_ =~ m//` to just `m//` which does the same
- Instead of `chomp($svr)` for each line, do it only once, right after initialization
- Reindented, so it's easier to see the block of code that belongs to the loop

Lastly, you can drop "defined" in `if ( defined $msg ) {`

Comment: All excellent improvements, thanks!  I will make these changes to the code.